# Lubridate or ANYTIME to convert from 24hr to 12hr time

Tags: r, lubridate, microsoft-r

As the title suggests, I am trying to use either lubridate or ANYTIME (or similar) to convert a time from 24 hour into 12 hour.. To make life easier I don't need the whole time converted.

What I mean is I have a column of dates in this format:

```
2021-02-15 16:30:33
```

I can use `inbound$Hour <- hour(inbound$Timestamp)` to grab just the hour from the Timestamp which is great.. except that it is still in 24hr time. (this creates an integer column for the hour number)

I have tried several mutates such as `inbound <- inbound %>% mutate(Hour = ifelse(Hour > 12, sum(Hour - 12),Hour)`

This technically works.. but I get some really wonky values (I get a -294 in several rows for example)..

is there an easier way to get the 12hr time converted?

Per recommendation below I tried to use a base FORMAT as follows:

```
inbound$Time <- format(inbound$Timestamp, "%H:%M:%S")
inbound$Time <- format(inbound$Time, "%I:%M:%S")
```

and on the second format I am getting an error

```
 Error in format.default(inbound$Time, "%I:%M:%S") : 
  invalid 'trim' argument
```

I did notice the first format converts to a class CHARACTER column.. not sure if that is causing issues with the 2nd format or not..

I then also tried:

```
 `inbound$time <- format(strptime(inbound$Timestamp, "%H:%M:%S"), "%I:%M %p")`
```

Which runs without error.. but it creates a full column of NA's

Final edit::::: I made the mistake of mis-reading/applying the solution and that caused errors.. when using the `inbound$Time <- format(inbound$Time, "%I:%M:%S")` or `as.numeric(format(inbound$Timestamp, "%I"))` from the comments... both worked and solved the issue I was having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear... From 2021-02-15 16:30:33 you want just 04:30:33 as a result?

No need for lubridate or anytime.  Assuming that is a Posixct

```
a <- as.POSIXct("2021-02-15 16:30:33")
a
# [1] "2021-02-15 16:30:33 UTC"

b <- format(a, "%H:%M:%S")
b
#[1] "16:30:33"

c <- format(a, "%I:%M:%S")
c
#[1] "04:30:33"
```

Comment: Yes, it begins as a Posixct.. and I have always struggled with date/times in base.. I never even thought about it being that simple.. you may have just saved the last 2 or 3 strands of hair on my head before I pulled them out..

Comment: Now that I am trying it.. this parses the time away from the date.. but I can't convert the time with the %I:%M:%S.. the previous step is converting to a class CHARACTER and I get an error.. updating my question with the attempt/error

Comment: What is your desired output? A numeric of just the hour?  Does as.numeric(format(X ,"%I")) work?

Comment: You create Time, then format Time again. No need. My solution was simply showing what was possible for format... Just use %I on the timestamp..

Comment: So, just tell me what you want the output to be - class and format and we can sort!

Comment: Sorry for delayed responses.. work today was stupid busy and I didn't get a chance to respond back.  But yes, ultimately all I need is the numeric values representing hours so that I can say that X number of observations fall into Y hour of each day.

And now after re-reading the original answer/suggestion.. I understand what you were saying.. at the time I was so frustrated I missed the forest for the trees..  Calum Polwart.. your answer also works for what I was hoping to get as well.

Thank you both!